# SSIS How to select user variable dynamically based on value of another user variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, oracle10g

I have a `ForEach` loop for importing all available tables in source connection. I am using following user variables for this:

- `OracleTables` of type `System.Object` for holding all tables from oracle DB
- `TableName` for enumerating `OracleTables` of type `String`
- set of `Boolean` variables (e.g. `Enable_TABLENAME`) one for each table to hold whether that table is to be imported or not.

Now, I want to configure the `DataFlow` task inside `ForEach` loop to run iff the value of corresponsing table variable if `true`. Basically, I want something like:

`!@[User::Enable_@[User::TableName]]` for `Disable` property of `DataFlow` task.

that is, I want to get the `Boolean` table variable for for current table held by `TableName` variable.

How can I achive this? Or else, is there any better way to do this? Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: @Siva I am following your answer to a post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298806/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-list-of-ms-access-tables-within-an-ssis-packag/6301687#6301687" with some modifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ForEach Item Ennumerator (you can define your Items in the editor itself) or NodeList Ennumerator (and have your values in an XML file) or ADO.Net Ennumerator ( have your values coming from a SQL table instead).