# Perform data conversion transformation in a SSIS DFT inside Foreach Loop Container

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, foreach-loop-container, ssis-data-flow

I have got around 35 tables whose data need to be migrated from SQL Server to MySQL. I am using SSIS for this project and I have set up a control flow (using [Load Multiple Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298806/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-list-of-ms-access-tables-within-an-ssis-packag/)) with a Script Task and a Foreach Loop Container that iterates through all the tables in my database. What I now need to do is convert the data type for some of the columns, in some of the tables, to 'Unicode String [DT_WSTR]' before I dump them in my destination tables. Is this something that can be done through SSIS? If so, any pointers or a set of instructions would be great.

Thanks,

Pratik Gandhi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a standard out-of-the-box task for SSIS.

1. Add a Data Flow Task.
2. Add a Data conversion component to the task
3. Add your source and destination servers
4. Map your columns, converting datatypes where required.

As always, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms140321.aspx) provides further help.

Comment: My DFT is inside the foreach container, so the table structure and no. of columns would be changing on each iteration, how do I, in that case, configure my data conversion task?