# Dynamically import Single mdb file with multiple tables into SQL Server using SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ssis, etl

I have a single MS Access `.mdb` file that contains multiple tables like

*Table name:*

```
UserLog_1_2019
UserLog_2_2019
User_Log_3_2019
```

For every month new table generate automatically.

I want to import above mentioned dynamically tables into SQL Server by using SSIS. How to achieve this scenario?

Thanks,
Lawrance A

Comment: Any chance of normalizing the data in the source Access DB to use one log table, with a field for User ID?

Comment: No, Creating new table for every month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer i will provide 2 approaches to achieve this:

1. using SSIS
2. using C#

## (1) SSIS approach

You must get the Access tables list into a variable of type System.Object, then loop over the tables names using a Foreach Loop container. There are many links that gives detailed informations, as example you can refer to the following SO answer it can gives you some insights:

- [How do I programmatically get the list of MS Access tables within an SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298806/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-list-of-ms-access-tables-within-an-ssis-packag)

## (2) C# approach

Recently i started a new project on Git-Hub, which is a class library developed using C#. You can use it to import tabular data from excel, word , powerpoint, text, csv, html, json and xml into SQL server table having a different schema definition using schema mapping approach. check it out at:

- [C# Schema mapping class library](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper)

You can use a similar code:

```
string con = @"Data Source=.\SQLInstance;Initial Catalog=tempdb;integrated security=SSPI;";

using (SchemaMapperDLL.Classes.Converters.MsAccessImport smAccess = new SchemaMapperDLL.Classes.Converters.MsAccessImport(@"U:\Passwords.mdb"))
{
    using (SchemaMapperDLL.Classes.SchemaMapping.SchemaMapper SM = new SchemaMapperDLL.Classes.SchemaMapping.SchemaMapper("dbo","passwords"))
    {
        SM.CreateDestinationTable(con);
        //Read Access
        smAccess.BuildConnectionString();
        smAccess.getSchemaTable();

        foreach (DataRow schRow in smAccess.SchemaTable.Rows)
        {
            string strTablename = schRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim('\'');

            DataTable dt = smAccess.GetTableByName(strTablename);
            bool result = SM.ChangeTableStructure(ref dt);

            if (result == true)
            {
                SM.InsertToSQLUsingSQLBulk(dt, con);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks....but I want to write query like SELECT * FROM UserLog_* or I should pass the table name into variable..

Comment: You can do both methods. But the easiest is passing the table name into variable

Comment: Exactly...I followed the Option 1 - SSIS Approach and got the expected solution

Comment: Is there any way to use SQL Query to load specific tables from .mdb files?

Comment: You can write a simple select query using `SQL Command` access mode in OLEDB Source